# Calling format function with a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, string-formatting

How can I call the format function with a list as arguments?

I want to do something like this:

```
spacing = "{:<2} "*10
l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
print spacing.format(l)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `*args` format:

```
spacing.format(*l)
```

This tells Python to apply each element of `l` as a separate argument to the `.format()` method.

Do note your `spacing` format could end up with too many or too few elements if you hardcode the count; perhaps use the length of `l` instead:

```
spacing = "{:<2} " * len(l)
```

or use `str.join()` to eliminate that last space:

```
spacing = ' '.join(['{:<2}'] * len(l))
```

Demo:

```
>>> l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
>>> spacing = ' '.join(['{:<2}'] * len(l))
>>> spacing.format(*l)
'A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J '
```

Comment: @thefourtheye: the [reference documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) calls them the `*expression` and `**expression` syntax.

Comment: I am not sure :( http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: The tutorial talks about argument unpacking, yes, but calls `*` an operator, which is technically not correct (it is not an operator). :-)

Comment: The tutorial is a little more fluid with terms; its focus is to teach newcomers in a concise and efficient manner the basics. Exact technical terms are less important, I think.

Comment: Agreed :) They might have mentioned `* operator` so that people can remember it by the multiplication operator.

Comment: Or instead of calling `len(l)`, iterate over `l` with `spacing = ' '.join('{:<2}' for element in l)`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: I'd spell that as `' '.join(['{:<2}' for _ in l])`, but the multiplication is faster.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - but why the list comp instead of generator expresion? Is multiplication faster if you take out the unnecessary []'s?

Comment: @Paul: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/100297; a list comp is faster when used with `str.join()`.